# RHEL 6.3 shell scripting

Tags: shell, scripting, rhel

What is wrong with this?

```
if [ ! -d "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" ] 
then     
     mkdir "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" 
     cd "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" 
else 
     cd"$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" 
fi
```

Errors : syntax error near unexpected token 'else'

What about ??

```
 if -f $LOCAL_EVENT_LOG_FTP_TEMP del $LOCAL_EVENT_LOG_FTP_TEMP

 else
     echo Event Log Backup Module not Activated.
 fi;
```

Is there any mistakes?

Comment: is your `fi` keyword on the same line as `cd"$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR"`

Comment: Dale : nope :) typo .

Comment: It was; it isn't now.

Answer (score 0):

The first edition of the question read:

```
if [ ! -d "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" ] 
then     
     mkdir "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR"

     cd "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" 
else 
     cd"$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" fi
```

I answered: You should not get a syntax error for that `else`. However, the `fi` is misplaced. It either needs a semicolon in front of it, or it should be on a line on its own.

```
if [ ! -d "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" ] 
then     
     mkdir "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" 
     cd "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" 
else 
     cd "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR"  # Note the space
fi
```

However, you really don't need the `else` clause at all:

```
if [ ! -d "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" ] 
then     
     mkdir "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" 
fi 
cd "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR"
```

Or even:

```
mkdir -p "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" || exit 1
cd "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR" || exit 1
```

The first `exit` is taken if the directory does not exist and cannot be created (e.g. because there's a file with the name that you want to be a directory, or you don't have permission).  Since `mkdir` reported the error, it is reasonable just to exit, but you can do any other error handling action you care to do. The second `exit` is taken if you can't `cd` to the directory — it almost certainly means you don't have permission, or someone managed to remove it between the time the `mkdir` command checked that it existed and the time when the `cd` was executed.

---

Your second example is:

```
if -f $LOCAL_EVENT_LOG_FTP_TEMP del $LOCAL_EVENT_LOG_FTP_TEMP

else
     echo Event Log Backup Module not Activated.
fi;
```

You are completely missing the `then` clause and an action for it. It looks as if you might be intending to test for a file and then delete it, but `del` is a Windows command (not a standard Unix command), and you need to use the test command (shell built-in command).

```
if [ -f $LOCAL_EVENT_LOG_FTP_TEMP ]
then del $LOCAL_EVENT_LOG_FTP_TEMP
else echo Event Log Backup Module not Activated.
fi
```

Remember, `[` is the name of the command; it must be separated from the `if` by spaces, and must be separated from its arguments by spaces, and the last argument must be `]` when you use the name `[` (but not when you use the name `test` instead).

Comment: Why dont need the Else?? I dont really understand yet about the sequences in RHEL ..

Comment: Because both the `then` and the `else` do `cd "$LOCAL_WORKING_DIR"` so you only need to write it once, after the `if...fi` statement, as shown.